# understand weird crash stack from android 13 device

Tags: android, selinux, tombstone

I have a android 13 device, below crash happen sometimes during bootup! but the crash stack not show the crash libname, how should I know where is the crash code line?

```
Cmdline: media.codec hw/android.hardware.media.omx@1.0-service
pid: 1197, tid: 4243, name: AdrenoOsLib  >>> media.codec <<<
uid: 1046
signal 0 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr --------
    r0  a82a9715  r1  00000081  r2  7fffffff  r3  00000000
    r4  a69c76f0  r5  a82a9715  r6  a8a6b000  r7  00000078
    r8  00000528  r9  a540b1c0  r10 a69c76a0  r11 00000000
    ip  a540b170  sp  a540b198  lr  a5b992a7  pc  a8a6b000

backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000000  /dev/__properties__/u:object_r:log_tag_prop:s0
```

Only one pc address is there, looks like selinux releated but do not see avc denial.